# making an object appear in a different position

Tags: unity-game-engine, move

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class Archer : MonoBehaviour
{
    Animator anim;
    NavMeshAgent nav;
    public Transform arrowInHand;
    public GameObject physicArrow;
    public GameObject bowString;
    public GameObject orignal;      // copy of bowstring
    public GameObject grab;         // right hand ref gameobject
  

    void Start()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        nav = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
    }
    
    //      Events from animations
    // -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

    public void GetArrow()
    {
        arrowInHand.transform.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }

    public void LoadArrow()
    {
        bowString.transform.position = grab.transform.position;     // *
        bowString.transform.SetParent(grab.transform, true);
    }

    public void LaunchArrow()
    {
        bowString.transform.SetParent(null, true);
        bowString.transform.position = orignal.transform.position;  // *

        Instantiate (physicArrow, arrowInHand.position, arrowInHand.rotation);
        arrowInHand.transform.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get the bowstring to move/teleport into the hand (grab), change parent, allow the animation to pull back the bowstring and then move/teleport the bowstring back to the orignal position (-0.13, 0, 0) during LaunchArrow. Everything I try doesn't work.  This code has no errors, but it doesn't work.  I've been at this all day and I'm a little annoyed.

Comment: frustration never leads to good times.  Personally Id have done this with an animation.  A bow string middle is not going to bend, nor is the bow.   however, drop the arrow firing bit, and concentrate on the bowstring action. if original hasnt moved.. then id expect it to work,

Comment: the firing arrow and the bowstring getting a new parent and moving back all work.  I just can't get the bowstring to move to grab and then move back to the orignal position.

Comment: well even that sentence is confusing.. You're saying getting a parent and moving it back all work.. if it works then the bowstring action works.. cos you just said so..

Comment: I gave up trying to move the bowstring and just parented it back to its' root - I got it to work